# Getting limit by Squeeze/Sandwich Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $b$ be a real number satisfying $b > 1$. 
Evaluate $\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\dfrac{b^{n} + b^{3n}}{1 + b^2}\right)^{1/n}$

---

Currently stuck at:

$$
%[(b^n)/(b^2)]^(1/n)≤[(b^n + b^(3n))/(1+b^2)]^(1/n)≤[(2b^(3n))/1+b^2]^(1/n)
\left(\dfrac{b^{n} }{b^2}\right)^{1/n} \leq
\left(\dfrac{b^{n} + b^{3n}}{1 + b^2}\right)^{1/n} \leq
\left(\dfrac{2b^{3n}}{1 + b^2}\right)^{1/n}
$$

I know that $\left(\dfrac{b^{n} }{b^2}\right)^{1/n} \!\!\!\to 1\,$ as $\,n\to\infty$.

I can't seem to find an expression in $n$ that is $\ge \left(\dfrac{2b^{3n}}{1 + b^2}\right)^{1/n}$ and whose limit is $1$ as well.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: The "I know" statement is wrong. That limit is $b.$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$\left(\frac{b^n+b^{3n}}{1+b^2}\right)^\frac{1}{n}=b\left(1+b^{2n}\right)^\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{1+b^2}\right)^\frac{1}{n}$$
Can you go from here? The limit is $b^3$.

Comment: can you show what is next to do from here?

Comment: Frog, so I am wrong in wanting to prove that the limit is 1? I should be proving that it is b^3 instead?

Comment: @Bhaskara-III: Use that $$\lim_n(a_nb_nc_n)=\lim_na_n\lim_nb_n\lim_nb_n$$ for converging sequences $a_n,b_n,c_n$... and for Keith: Yes the limit is $b^3$.

Comment: Am I right to say that:
[b^(2n)]^(1/n) ≤ [1+b^(2n)]^(1/n) ≤ [2b^(2n)]^(1/n)
=> b^2 ≤ [1+b^(2n)]^(1/n) ≤ 2^(1/n) x b^2
=> lim b^2 = lim 2^(1/n) x b^2 = b^2?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the theorems you want, you can evaluate this limit this way:

Assume $b\ge1$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{b^n+b^{3n}}{1+b^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left[\ln\left(\left(\frac{b^n+b^{3n}}{1+b^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)\right]=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left[\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{b^n+b^{3n}}{1+b^2}\right)\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left[\frac{\ln\left(\frac{b^n+b^{3n}}{1+b^2}\right)}{n}\right]=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left[\frac{\ln(b)\left(3-\frac{2}{1+b^{2n}}\right)}{1}\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left[\ln(b)\left(3-\frac{2}{1+b^{2n}}\right)\right]=$$
$$\exp\left[\ln(b)\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(3-\frac{2}{1+b^{2n}}\right)\right]=\exp\left[\ln(b)\left(3-0\right)\right]=\exp\left[3\ln(b)\right]=b^3$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The expression is greater than
$$\left(\dfrac{b^{3n}}{1 + b^2}\right)^{1/n} = \frac{b^3}{(1+b^2)^{1/n}}$$

and less than

$$\left(\dfrac{2b^{3n}}{1 + b^2}\right)^{1/n} = \frac{2^{1/n}b^3}{(1+b^2)^{1/n}}.$$